# What is the purpose of the m_samWOW64 public data member of ATL::CRegKey?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, atl

The `ATL::CRegKey` class has a *public* data member named `m_samWOW64` of type `REGSAM`.

This data member is usually initialized to 0, but in some `CRegKey` methods, like `CRegKey::Create`, it is set like this:

> ```
>     ...
>     m_hKey = hKey;
> #if WINVER >= 0x0501
>     m_samWOW64 = samDesired & (KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
> #endif
> ```

So, what is the purpose of this public data member?

From the code above, it seems to me that `m_samWOW64` is used to keep track of the [WOW64 access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view) specified in `CRegKey::Create`.

However, if a *raw* `HKEY` is attached to a `CRegKey` instance via `CRegKey::Attach`, this data member is set to zero.

Reading the `CRegKey` implementation code, there are some methods that set that data member as shown above for `CRegKey::Create`, and other methods that simply set it to 0. In other words, this data member *cannot always* be trusted as storing the WOW64 access of the associated key.

Moreover, there is *no reference* to this `m_samWOW64` public data member in the [MSDN documentation of ATL::CRegKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cregkey-class?view=msvc-160#public-data-members).

So, should the `m_samWOW64` public data member simply be *ignored* in C++ client code that uses `ATL::CRegKey`?

Is it a leftover from the past?
Or is there a documentation bug and MSDN is wrongly missing information about this data member?

Comment: It's not documented as such because the `samDesired` attribute https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cregkey-class?view=msvc-170#create documentation points to the win32 documentation for registry access security flags. This is to support accessing alternate registry views : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view you can pass `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` to `Create` and it will be kept internally in the class so future access by the class will be consistent.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have issues with your “consistency”. As I wrote in the question, that data member is properly set only by *some* methods like `Create()`, but not set (or better: just cleared) by other methods like `Attach(HKEY)`.

Comment: Attach attaches to an existing handle, it's too late to specify security attributes.

Comment: @SimonMourier So, this is a confirmation of what I wrote in the question: _”In other words, this data member cannot always be trusted as storing the WOW64 access of the associated key.”_ Some official MSDN documentation about that would be welcome.

Comment: Why does it matter if it can't be trusted if the member is not documented for you to use?

Comment: @Anders So should that PUBLIC member be ignored?? If so, why didn’t they make it PRIVATE? Is this a MSDN doc bug?? Should this PUBLIC member be documented instead? And, what is the point of your comment?? I _already_ wrote those questions in my request.